# Unable to compile xpath with '$' character in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I trying to click on a element using the below xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RadialTimePickerView$RadialPickerTouchHelper[@index='4']")).click();
```

but it is giving me below error

Caused by: `org.jaxen.XPathSyntaxException: Unexpected '$'`

Comment: Are you sure the `xpath` is correct? it doesn't look like html tag.

Comment: I think your Xpath format is not correct.

Comment: Xpath is correct I am using it in case of appium (So firstly we use tag name as class name then attribute = value format)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630295/can-not-make-xpath-with-functions-work-with-jdom2

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a valid XPath node test is given by https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-31-20170321/#node-tests. It basically boils down to that allowed names are defined by https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name, and this does not include the $ sign.

So Selenium is correct in complaining that the `$` sign is not allowed.

You might be able to use some other location technique provided by Selenium, though.